# Using Google Custom Search Engine through the google-api-client gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search, google-api

I'm trying to wrap up a rather basic search using the Google Custom Search Engine API.
The problem I'm facing is that the only results I'm apparently able to get are the first 10:

```
module WalterSobchak
  class GoogleCustomSearch
    def initialize
      @client = Google::APIClient.new(
        key: configatron.google.api_key, authorization: nil)
      @search = @client.discovered_api('customsearch')
    end

    def query(q, num)
      @client.execute(api_method: @search.cse.list,
        parameters: {q: q, startIndex: num,
                     key: configatron.google.api_key,
                     cx: configatron.google.custom_search_engine})
    end
  end
end
```

This code is quite simple but works quite well: first of all I initialize my GCS client using my api_key, I can then call it with whatever parameter I like, for example:

```
client.query('poker', 10)
```

to search my Custom Engine with the string 'poker' and starting from the 10th element of the resultset. My problem is that it doesn't work, I alway get the same result I would get without the startIndex option. The problem is probably that I have no idea if that parameter is named that way, or if it's the right one I can use: I've tried startIndex, start, start_index, num (this one works, but max value is 10, and I need at least 30 results), sometimes the parameter is rejected, sometimes it doesn't cause any effect.

Has anyone done something like this before and can help me?

Comment: I'm just guessing here - maybe the option name should be `start_index` and not `startIndex`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the API Explorer: https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/customsearch/v1/search.cse.list

It looks like the parameter you're looking for is 'start': The index of the first result to return (integer). The other parameter (num) is the number of results returned.

You can try manually on the Explorer and see why it's not returning what you need to.